# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'future'

Tags: python

I have a Python script that I am trying to run in Linux via a bash script called ./launch.sh.  When I launch the code I get the following error returned.

```
[user@localhost mktdata.out]$ ./launch.sh 
[user@localhost mktdata.out]$ Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "strats/merlin.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "strats/merlin/mktdata.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "strats/dao/utils/itertools.py", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'future'
```

Line 1 in the Python script `itertools.py` line 1 that the error is referring to is:

```
from future.moves.itertools import zip_longest
```

Is there a package that I need to install in order for this code to work?

Comment: `pip3 install future`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import [future](https://python-future.org/) like this:

```
from __future__ import *
```

In the event that fails, use pip to install it like this (Use sudo for MAC):

```
pip install future
```

[Here](https://python-future.org/quickstart.html#installation) is more on installing future.